# Terraform: Parse an input JSON and add matching key values to a list

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I have a python externa_data_source giving me IPs in a flat JSON:

```
{\"start\":\"55.555.100.101\",\"end\":\"55.555.100.174\",\"start\":\"40.00.000.161\",\"end\":\"40.00.000.174\"}
```

I need to create azure mysql firewall rules matching the start and end IPs. So I tried this:

```
resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "ip_rule" {
  name                = format("iprule-%s", count.index)
  count               = length(values(data.external.python.result))/2
  resource_group_name = module.resource-group.name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_flexible_server.example.name
  start_ip_address    = element(data.external.python.result.start, count.index)
  end_ip_address      = element(data.external.python.result.end, count.index)
}
```

It's failing with:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on mysql_flexible.tf line 105, in resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "ip_rule":
 105:   start_ip_address    = element(data.external.python.result.start, count.index)
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | data.external.python.result.start is "40.70.173.161"

Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
```

I've tried so many different approaches but I can't get it to work in any way. Any help please?

Comment: Can you show us the Python script ?

Comment: Please explain why the `element` function is being used on a string type input. Without further information this seems like a typo where `element(data.external.python.result.start, count.index)` should be replaced with `data.external.python.result.start`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vhn"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-shhn"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  delegation {
    name = "fs"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server" "example" {
  name                   = "examplekfs"
 location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  administrator_login    = "psqladmin"
  administrator_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  backup_retention_days  = 7
  delegated_subnet_id    = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  sku_name               = "GP_Standard_D2ds_v4"
}


resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "ip_rule" {
  name                = format("iprule-%s", count.index)
  count               = length(data.external.powershell_ip_ranges.result)
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_flexible_server.example.name
   start_ip_address =data.external.powershell_ip_ranges.result.start

   end_ip_address = data.external.powershell_ip_ranges.result.end
}


data "external" "powershell_ip_ranges" {
  program = ["powershell", "-Command", "C:\\...path\\ipranges.ps1"]
}



output "test" {
  value = data.external.powershell_ip_ranges.result.start
}
```

I have the Ip values in the following format in the file path which are mapped string values  :

```
$ips=@{}
for($i=0; $i -lt $ipRanges.Length; $i++) {
    $ips["start"] = $ipRanges[$i].start
    $ips["end"] = $ipRanges[$i].end
}
$ips | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

So it needed ,

```
 start_ip_address =data.external.powershell_ip_ranges.result.start
   end_ip_address = data.external.powershell_ip_ranges.result.end
```

[image]